# Issue in capturing image with front and back camera one by one

Tags: android

In my Android application I am trying to capture image with front and back camera one by one and saving it as two different `.jpg` image files. But my code is throwing `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` Exception. Please tel what is the issue with my code?

**Code:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.appname;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static int camface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        takeSnapShots(this,Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        takeSnapShots(this,Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    }


    private void takeSnapShots(Context context, int face) {

        camface = face;
        SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(context);
        Camera camera = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int camIdx=0; camIdx<cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == face) {
                camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
            }
        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
    }


    private static Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator+"picture_"+camface+".jpg";
            File pictureFile = new File(path);

            if (pictureFile.exists())
                pictureFile.delete();

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.setRotate(-90);
                realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(realImage, 0, 0, realImage.getWidth(), realImage.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**AndroidManifest.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appdeveloper.appname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gef.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: `camera = Camera.open(camIdx);`

Comment: Can you show us your androidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Alex I have added `AndroidManifest.xml` in my question

Comment: @Salu try to add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />` and tell us, if it helps.

Comment: @Alex getting same exception even after adding `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />`

Comment: Ok, next question. What is the target android version (for example 5.0 Lollipop)?

Comment: @Alex `minSdkVersion 19` and `targetSdkVersion 25`