# how to capture two pictures on one click

Tags: android

I want to capture two pictures on one button click, one picture from front camera and other picture from back camera. I have tried different approaches but every time I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`. I have already posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518313/issue-in-capturing-image-with-front-and-back-camera-one-by-one) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521403/how-to-capture-two-pictures-on-one-button-click-one-with-front-and-one-with-ba) question related to this issue. Please tell how can I get my job done. I looking for solution since many days.

Answer (score 0):

Your error raises because you must release your front camera and then open your back camera to be able to use it.